# How to set ClamAV for manual-only work in Linux (no automatic cron tasks)

Tags: cron, clamav

The reason I ask this is to save resources. I try to save automated cron tasks wherever I can.

Say one installs CalmAV in an Ubuntu based, Apache server, via the command:

```
apt-get update # apt-get install clamav
```

How do you then set the program, through the terminal, to work in an all-manual mode, without any task being performed automatically from cron?

Edit: My VPS is 2 Core processor, 40GB SSD, 2GB RAM, 3TB transfer, Ubuntu 16.0.

Comment: Did you look to /etc/crontab? or inside /var/spool/cron/crontabs/ directory?

Comment: No, I didn't know these concepts; I thought cron is part of Apache and not of Ubuntu. I am very fresh in VPS.

Comment: Cron is a unix service and is available in most of the distributions and operating systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific task, you'd do `dpkg-reconfigure -plow clamav-freshclam` and select `manual`.

Note however that `freshclam` which updates databases uses minuscule amount of resources (runs one per hour for less than a second if there are no updates), and that `clamav` with outdated databases is a big problem.

So running update manually every day or so to save 0.01% of system resources is not only big waste of your time (and can lead to less protected server if you're not fast enough), but may actually even use more resources as just the act of your logging in to the server need some resources (which are still so minuscule as to be totally unimportant)

So you're better off leaving it at defaults in this case.

Comment: You mean it's better off just instaling and that's it? No resources change? Thanks.

Comment: @Benia yes, just install it and that's it.

Comment: Wow! What you say indeed surprise me, as some people who (seemingly) never used it, told me "It will take huge amount of resources, don't install it!", and things like this... Haha...

Comment: BTW, my VPS is 2 Core processor, 40GB SSD, 2GB RAM, 3TB transfer, Ubuntu 16.0.